# Is there any equivalent method for Oracle's INSERT ALL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to install records to two different tables based on some conditions in SQL Server. In Oracle there is a method called `INSERT ALL` to insert in to different tables based on conditions like below.

```
insert all
  when loc in ('NEW YORK', 'BOSTON') THEN
   into dept_east(deptno, dname, loc) values(deptno, dname, loc)
  when loc in ('CHICAGO') THEN
   into dept_mid(deptno, dname, loc) values(deptno, dname, loc)
  else
   into dept_west(deptno, dname, loc) values(deptno, dname, loc)
select deptno, dname, loc
  from dept
```

Is there any method in SQL to directly insert into multiple tables. I've tried using MERGE statement also.

Comment: In SQL Server, any DML statement can only affect a single table - but your motivating example looks like something for which [Partitioned Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) might be (part of) the solution.

Comment: Note that SQL Server supports procedural SQL by default, so you can easily send multiple logical commands as a single command, including whatever conditions you need. And indeed, separating data like this smells quite a bit - partitioned tables are probably a better choice. Keep your data normalized if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent. Execute multiple insert statements.

If your table structure lends itself to using partitioned views you might look into that. It's the only way to truly insert into multiple tables in one statement in SQL Server.